# Keep the n highest values of each row of an numpy array and zero everything else

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of data where I need to keep only `n` highest values, and zero everything else.

My current solution:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(30)

# keep only the n highest values
n = 3

# Simple 2x5 data field for this example, real life application will be exteremely large
data = np.random.random((2,5))
#[[ 0.64414354  0.38074849  0.66304791  0.16365073  0.96260781]
# [ 0.34666184  0.99175099  0.2350579   0.58569427  0.4066901 ]]


# find indices of the n highest values per row
idx = np.argsort(data)[:,-n:]
#[[0 2 4]
# [4 3 1]]


# put those values back in a blank array
data_ = np.zeros(data.shape) # blank slate
for i in xrange(data.shape[0]):
    data_[i,idx[i]] = data[i,idx[i]]

# Each row contains only the 3 highest values per row or the original data
#[[ 0.64414354  0.          0.66304791  0.          0.96260781]
# [ 0.          0.99175099  0.          0.58569427  0.4066901 ]]
```

In the code above, `data_` has the `n` highest values and everything else is zeroed out. This works out nicely even if `data.shape[1]` is smaller than `n`. But the only issue is the `for loop`, which is slow because my actual use case is on very very large arrays.

Is it possible to get rid of the for loop?

Answer (score 7):

You could act on the result of `np.argsort` -- np.argsort *twice*, the first to get the index order and the second to get the ranks -- in a vectorized fashion, and then use either `np.where` or simply multiplication to zero everything else:

```
In [116]: np.argsort(data)
Out[116]: 
array([[3, 1, 0, 2, 4],
       [2, 0, 4, 3, 1]])

In [117]: np.argsort(np.argsort(data))  # these are the ranks
Out[117]: 
array([[2, 1, 3, 0, 4],
       [1, 4, 0, 3, 2]])

In [118]: np.argsort(np.argsort(data)) >= data.shape[1] - 3
Out[118]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [119]: data * (np.argsort(np.argsort(data)) >= data.shape[1] - 3)
Out[119]: 
array([[ 0.64414354,  0.        ,  0.66304791,  0.        ,  0.96260781],
       [ 0.        ,  0.99175099,  0.        ,  0.58569427,  0.4066901 ]])

In [120]: np.where(np.argsort(np.argsort(data)) >= data.shape[1]-3, data, 0)
Out[120]: 
array([[ 0.64414354,  0.        ,  0.66304791,  0.        ,  0.96260781],
       [ 0.        ,  0.99175099,  0.        ,  0.58569427,  0.4066901 ]])
```

Comment: I edited my solution for clarity. Yours doesn't yield n highest values per row using the data above. Try to use your solution with the same data to see the difference.

Comment: @Fnord: oops, forgot an extra `argsort`.  It takes another argsort to get it to behave like rankdata (I'm used to just using .rank('dense') on a Series or DataFrame.)